# How to echo a specific key => value pair from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm accessing an API in my local network. I need to use some values for other things, but I do not know how to get a specific key=>value pair from this JSON array.

To get the JSON, I have:

```
$url = 'http://192.168.123.123/api/dev';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$resultData = json_decode($result);
//echo "<pre>";
print_r($resultData);
echo "<br>";
```

Which gives me:

```
 stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [1E5410ECC9D90FC3] => stdClass Object ( [type] => BB-TH [state] => normal [alarm] => stdClass Object ( [state] => none [severity] => ) [name] => Watchdog 15 [label] => Watchdog 15 [entity] => stdClass Object ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Watchdog 15 [alarm] => stdClass Object ( [state] => none [severity] => ) [measurement] => stdClass Object ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => temperature [value] => 62.61 [state] => normal [alarm] => stdClass Object ( [state] => clear [severity] => ) [units] => F [datalogEnabled] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [type] => humidity [value] => 47 [state] => normal [alarm] => stdClass Object ( [state] => none [severity] => ) [datalogEnabled] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [type] => dewpoint [value] => 42.13 [state] => normal [alarm] => stdClass Object ( [state] => none [severity] => ) [units] => F [datalogEnabled] => 1 ) ) ) ) [layout] => stdClass Object ( [0] => Array ( [0] => entity/0 ) ) [order] => 0 [temperatureOffset] => 0 [snmpInstance] => 1 ) ) [retCode] => 0 [retMsg] => )
```

All I need is:

```
temperature [value] => 62.61
```

but I don't know the syntax to get it.

Comment: That doesn't look like a decoded JSON.

Comment: Why did you edit your question? `json_decode()` is correct.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Lemme change it back real quick.

Comment: Show what you tried and what the result was

Comment: @NigelRen If I hadn't already casted my "duplicate question" vote then I would definitely use yours!

Comment: Reason I still posted a question is because of how ridiculous the array looked to me. I didn't even know where to begin. Thanks for posting the other questions. Still trying to figure it out though.

Comment: A tip for future questions, don't post arrays as one liners. It's impossible to read. That limits your potential answers to the very few who has the strength to decode your array.

Comment: Want me to fix it?

Comment: Actually, it won't let me. It says my post is "mostly code". I give up.

Comment: If that is the case then you have not followed the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve do you need to post the full json or is there a irrelevant part that can be deleted?

Comment: If you solved your own question, **DO NOT** edit the question to add the answer. Questions are questions, answers are answers. If the question is closed however, it's **bad**, and you should work to reopen it before posting an answer.

Comment: THUR YES THUR!!

Answer (score -3):

https://ideone.com/GowSeA

```
 $temperature = $json->data->{'1E5410ECC9D90FC3'}->entity->{'0'}->measurement->{0};
```

Comment: The $str variable in that link is static, correct? This will be a dynamic value I need to access.

Comment: I don't care where you will get that string from. That is just an example you've provided and the important part is just about how to access elements in json object using php.

Comment: I figured it out and posted it in my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371470/what-is-the-point-of-flagging).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. -- see [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Comment: (1) (as the meta post mentioned, it depends on context. For some very-short code snippet it may not be necessary, although a link to docs of relevant functions can be more helpful. For long code it is definitely necessary.) (2) It's considered bad practice on [so] to answer bad questions (see the close reasons for possible reasons for a question being bad: unclear/debug question lacks MCVE/duplicate/...) If you can, please improve the question to be good and then answer.